# EOF to redirect a file or taking input from stdin

Tags: c

I have designed a parser with some state transitions. Now i want to redirect a file into my parser created in C to give the tokens.

My design is such that I need a space(' ') at the end of my string, that is  , I need to append a space character to the string read from the file or stdin. But the problem is the indexing.
For redirecting from a file i need to do

```
int length=0;

while((c1=getchar())!=EOF)
{
a[length]=c1;
length ++;
}
a[length-1]=' ';
a[length]=EOF;
```

While for reading from stdin, i need to do

```
int length=0;
while((c1=getchar())!=EOF)
{
a[length]=c1;
length ++;
}
a[length]=' ';
a[length+1]=EOF;
```

The input can come both from a stdin input or a file redirection(eg ./a.out < a.c) Now how do I do incorporate if these in my code, based on the type of input???

Comment: Both these inputs are *exactly the same* as far as your program is concerned. Both make the data available on stdin.

Comment: You should never **assign** `EOF` to anything! EOF is a concept, not a value. Your data should just end.

Comment: In the first code snippet you overwrite the last character read with a space, is that the intention? And why do you need to add a space anyway? Either just add anything more and use the `length` variable to know the length, or terminate it as a proper string with a `'\0'` character.

Answer (score 3):

First off, both `cat data | ./a.out` and `./a.out < data` produce exactly the same effect, namely that the program's `stdin` reads the file.

Perhaps what you want is a syntax like `./a.out data`. For this, I'd suggest a loop like this:

```
void process_my_data(FILE *);  // main logic here!

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if (argc == 1)
    {
        process_my_data(stdin);
    }
    else
    {
        while (--argc)
        {
            FILE * f = fopen(argv[argc], "rb");
            process_my_data(f);
            fclose(f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Even file redirection is giving me as argc=1 , when i use ./a.out < a4.c
. It should be 3 right? Why is it not? WHat to do

Comment: And use `fgetc(f)` instead of `getchar` from within `process_my_data`.

Comment: @user1506031 The `./a.out < a4.c` syntax means "send the content of a4.c to the stdin of a.out with `argc=1, argv={'./a.out'}` as the arguments". Doing `./a.out a4.c` results in stdin connected to user input and arguments `argc=2, argv={'./a.out', 'a4.c'}`.

Comment: @user1506031: No no no. `./aout < a4.c` has `argc == 1` -- there are *no* postional arguments! The indirection is processed by your shell and never seen by the program.